# Bchron NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 4)

Tags: r

I have been working with Bchron packages these days and it was working perfectly fine and all of a sudden, with the same data, I got this error:

> Error in (function (y, p, mu, phi)  : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 4)

When I enter:

```
for (j in 1:10) {
  DevChronOut = Bchronology(ages=Input$dates*1000,
                            ageSds=Input$sds*1000, 
                            calCurves=rep("normal",18),
                            positions=Input$depths*1000, 
                            positionThicknesses=Input$thickness*1000,
                            ids=Input$ids, 
                            jitterPositions = TRUE,
                            predictPositions=seq(356000,417000,by=100),iterations=10000)
}
```

There is not Na data or others into the file Input.

When I ask for traceback, 
I got this:

> 6: (function (y, p, mu, phi) 
>          {
>              return(.C("dtweediep1", as.double(y), as.double(p), as.double(mu), 
>                  as.double(phi), as.double(0))[5][[1]])
>          })(y = dots[[1L]][[1L]], p = dots[[2L]][[1L]], mu = dots[[3L]][[1L]], 
>              phi = dots[[4L]][[1L]])
>       5: mapply(FUN = function (y, p, mu, phi) 
>          {
>              return(.C("dtweediep1", as.double(y), as.double(p), as.double(mu), 
>                  as.double(phi), as.double(0))[5][[1]])
>          }, y = 0.598000000000013, p = 1.2, mu = 0, phi = Inf, MoreArgs = list(), 
>              SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
>       4: do.call("mapply", c(FUN = FUN, args[dovec], MoreArgs = list(args[!dovec]), 
>              SIMPLIFY = SIMPLIFY, USE.NAMES = USE.NAMES))
>       3: dtweediep1(theta[do[j + 1]] - thetaNew, p, mu * (diffPosition[j]), 
>              psi/(diffPosition[j])^(p - 1))
>       2: ifelse(j == n, 0, log(dtweediep1(theta[do[j + 1]] - thetaNew, 
>              p, mu * (diffPosition[j]), psi/(diffPosition[j])^(p - 1))))
>       1: Bchronology(ages = Input$dates * 1000, ageSds = Input$sds * 1000, 
>              calCurves = rep("normal", 18), positions = Input$depths * 
>                  1000, positionThicknesses = Input$thickness * 1000, ids = Input$ids, 
>              jitterPositions = TRUE, predictPositions = seq(356000, 417000, 
>                  by = 100), iterations = 10000)

Is there anything I can do ?

Comment: we probably need a reproducible example.  Since Bchron hasn't been updated in a year, it's **overwhelmingly** likely that you made a small change to your environment/data/processing pipeline somewhere that broke things.

Comment: Please provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)